# Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context.xml]

how can i resolve this  guys?

this my context.xml:

> ```
> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
>   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
>
>   <context:component-scan base-package="id.sisi.forca.test.app.ForcaServerAplication" />
>
> </beans>
> ```

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution for the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did this occurred while creating maven packaging jar-with-dependencies and executing jar?

Faced same namespace issue while maven packaging jar in `maven-assembly-plugin`

By changing the maven plugin to `maven-shade-plugin` resolve the namespace issue. Got the answer from below post:
[[Stackoverflow]unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335203/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-error#)